# Get Title of all windows exist in WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf

I am new to WPF and want to know that how to get title of all windows exist in wpf application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    List<string> titles = new List<string>();
    foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        titles.Add(w.Title);
    }
```

As long as this code is called on UI thread you should be fine with it.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.. This loop gives windows those are currently open... I need to get Name of all windows whether they are open or not..

Thanks again

Comment: I don't understand your need. If you are referring to finding all windows that will open at some point then there is no simple solution for this. Do you want to query the current application for all _System.Windows.Window_ derivates?